# Eclipse PDE looking for the absolute path for the file (or relative path)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

This is the code that I have for now but the output from this is: /Users/zakariasfridriksson/runtime-EclipseApplication/is.ru.cs.PapyrusActivityLogger.example (runtime-EclipseApplication this is wrong like it is missing some part of the path)

Code:

```
IProject project = root.getProject("is.ru.cs.PapyrusActivityLogger.example");
System.out.println(project.getFullPath());
IFile csv = project.getFile("logger.csv");
String finaldestination = root.getLocation().toString() + project.getFullPath();
System.out.println(finaldestination);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `getLocation` on the `IFile`:

```java
IPath csvPath = csv.getLocation();

String dest = csvPath.toOSString();
```

Note: `runtime-EclipseApplication` is the test workspace that Eclipse has created for you when you run plug-ins using 'Run as Eclipse Application'. So your original code is also giving the correct result.